# Create a trigger that changes a column in the inserted rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I need to create a trigger in SQL Server that renames the description of a procedure.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDV2H.jpg)

After performing the insert, the trigger must check if the column "no_stepdescription" has the name "TOMOGRAFIA" at the beginning of the description, if any, it must perform an update to abbreviate the text to "T.C".

In the attached image, the first record is named "COMPUTERIZED CRANIAL TOMOGRAPHY". In this case, I would like the trigger to perform an update to abbreviate that name to "T.C COMPUTADORIZADA DE CRANIO"
This abbreviation should only occur if the word "TOMOGRAPHY" appears at the beginning of the description.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Why would you do that in a trigger? Seems wrong in so many ways...

Comment: Why is the application layer not handling this, or the procedure that is being called?

Comment: Oh you're not trying to update the description of a *procedure* you're trying to update a column in your row... thats slightly more normal I guess

Comment: Yeah, the use of "procedure" in the title is *very* misleading, @DaleK ; it suggests a (mass) use of `sp_rename`.

Comment: yes, it's possible. Create an after insert trigger and update the target table joined on the inserted pseudo-table. Read about sql server triggers here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5909/sql-server-trigger-example/

Answer (score 0):

A typical trigger would look like this

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER Change_TOMOGRAFIA ON YourTable
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL(@@PROCID) > 1
    RETURN;    -- prevent recursion
IF NOT UPDATE(no_stepdescription) OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)
    RETURN;    -- early bail-out for 0 rows

UPDATE t
SET no_stepdescription = STUFF(t.no_stepdescription, 1, LEN('TOMOGRAFIA'), 'T.C')
FROM YourTable t
JOIN inserted i ON i.your_primary_key = t.your_primary_key
WHERE i.no_stepdescription LIKE 'TOMOGRAFIA %';
```

Note the use of a join back to the original table using the primary key. The `inserted` table may have zero or multiple rows, and you cannot modify it directly.